# PHP fread() chunk length not taken into acount correctly

Tags: php, size, fread, chunks

I want to send an external MP4 file in chunks of 1 MB each to a user. With each chunk I update a database entry to keep track of the download progress. I use fread() to read the file in chunks. Here is the stripped down code:

```
$filehandle = fopen($file, 'r');

while(!feof($filehandle)){
  $buffer = fread($filehandle, 1024*1024);

  //do some database stuff

  echo $buffer;
  ob_flush();
  flush(); 
}
```

However, when I check the chunk size at some iteration inside the while loop, with

```
$chunk_length = strlen($buffer);
die("$chunk_length");
```

I do never get the desired chunk size. It fluctates somewhere around 7000 - 8000 bytes. Nowhere near 1024*1024 bytes.
When I decrease the chunk size to a smaller number, for example 1024 bytes, it works as expected.

Comment: Did you open in binary mode? Not sure if this would be the cause, but who knows.

Comment: Yes, tried to open in binary mode but it did not change the behavior.

Comment: The description section in here describes scenarios where the actual read length won't match the length requested: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php - I'm guessing condition 4 is what's happening?

Comment: According to 4th condition:
"When reading from anything that is not a regular local file, reading will stop after a packet is available."

So, from this I understand that it is **never** possible to read more than 1 packet if the file is remote?

Comment: Why do you want this anyway? I don't see the point of splitting up a download.

Comment: To keep track of the status of the download. In other words: how much percent is/was downloaded. Sometimes downloads fail, or users abort. I want to keep track of that, by storing how much was downloaded.

Comment: But the user will end up with a bunch of files. How will they be put into one?

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP `fread()` manual:

> "When reading from anything that is not a regular local file, such as
>   streams returned when reading remote files or from popen() and
>   fsockopen(), reading will stop after a packet is available."

In this case I opened a remote file. Apparently, this makes `fread()` stop not at the specified length, but when the first package has arrived.

I wanted to keep track of a download of an external file.
If you to do this (or keep track of an upload), use CURL instead:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'callbackFunction');

function callbackFunction($download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded){
  //do stuff with the parameters
}
```